# How to change css dynamically after click? And after again click go back to default?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have problem little problem... unfortunately big for me yet... I prepared demo for you guys:

```js
$('#rulerSlider').click(function() {
  $('#canvas').css({
    'margin-left': '0px',
    'margin-top': '0px'
  });
});
```

```css
#justdraw {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px
}

#ruler {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#canvas {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

/* slider */ 
.slider {
  bottom: 350px;
  left: 300px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 26px;
  background: #333;
  /*margin: 20px auto;*/
  margin-left: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.slider:after {
  content: 'OFF';
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 0;
  font: 12px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}

.slider:before {
  content: 'ON';
  color: #3bb100;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 1px;
  z-index: 0;
  font: 12px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.slider label {
  display: block;
  width: 34px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #fcfff4;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.slider input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.slider input[type=checkbox]:checked+label {
  left: 43px;
}

/* end slider */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="justdraw">
  <div id="ruler">
    <div id="canvas">
      <canvas id="diagram" width="2100" height="2100">
      </canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="slider">
    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="rulerSlider" name="check" checked />
    <label for="rulerSlider"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**I have problems with the following steps:**
0. Slider default state is (ON)
1. Click the slider (OFF)
2. Delete margins 20 from *#justdraw*

```
#justdraw {
  margin-left: 20px; /* ---> margin-left: 0px;   */
  margin-top: 20px   /* ---> margin-right: 0px;  */
}
```

3. Click the slider again (ON)
4. Add margins 20 to *#justdraw*

```
#justdraw {
  margin-left: 0px; /* ---> margin-left: 20px;   */
  margin-top: 0px   /* ---> margin-right: 20px;  */
}
```

Can someone help? I am done with this... I tried using javascript a little but without succes.

Comment: Make a class that has the "off" settings in it.  Toggle the class.  Also, always include your logic in your question, not just a fiddle.  Don't force people to go to an offsite resource to find your code, which can over time become broken or unreachable

Comment: Sorry man i still don't know how to put code directly in my post ;<

Comment: Edit your post, hit the `<>` button or type Ctrl+M to bring up the on site editor

Comment: Ok, so now, make a `.off` css rule that has your margin left and margin top stuff in it. And on click `toggleClass('off')` https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass

Comment: thanks! i will try

Comment: $('#canvas').toggleClass('zero-margin'); // there would be class in css named zero-margin

Comment: $( "rulerSlider" ).toggleClass(function() {
  if ( $( this ).parent().is( ".off" ) ) {
    return "justdrawOFF";
  } else {
    return "justdraw";
  }
});


Something like that? If yes, then can you tell me how that "if" should be look like, because it's still don't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Brarod

Try this code to add and remove css, it works properly.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn4").click(function(){
    $("#toggle1").toggleClass("intro");
  });

});
    </script>
    <style>
        .intro {
            font-size: 200%;
            background-color:black;
            text-shadow:1px 2px 3px yellow;
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Tenth Demo Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h3>Toggle Class</h3>
        <p id="toggle1">Hello!! This My Tenth Demo Page....<code>◙♣♣♣♣☼╧@á</code></p>
        <button id="btn4">Add Toggle Class</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope above code will be useful for you.

Thank you.